# editing titles, flagging for assistance

Tags: discussion, flags, title, declined-flags

Some time ago I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169576/how-to-call-a-method-after-changed-dependencyproperty) and thought to myself that the title didn't really address the issue that the OP was having. I realize how the user was thinking when he wrote the question, but actually the issue he has can be generalized to a very different problem.

So I thought I should improve the title. And as I have spent time on stackoverflow.com I have learned that they should have a nice hit rate on Google so that other users can find it. It should have the correct terms that other people search on to improve it being found. And as such I didn't feel confident enough to edit it, because I don't have the knowledge to improve it.

So I flagged the question. And I wrote that:

> Title change: I would edit the title to say something about addressing
>   object specific methods from the static `DependencyObject.Changed`,
>   but I am not sure what would be better.. I think more people will find
>   it if it says something about the static-to-instance relationship,
>   which is actually what the OP is having an issue with.

but the flag was declined

> declined - Why are you telling us? You can edit, or submit an edit for
>   review.

I still feel that it can be improved. I still don't know how to improve it.

How should I handle this situation?

Comment: Flagging is a bad idea for improvement of title, flags are for more serious work.

Comment: I +1'd this for seeking to improve a post, and for asking about things when what you tried did not work... not to encourage the use of flags for this sort of thing.

Comment: **Click the *edit* link underneath the question.**

Comment: @TheEstablishment I know how to edit a question.. no need to be sarcastic

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking then. It wasn't sarcastic. That's the appropriate solution to this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flags are for slightly more serious things. Don't flag anything for an action that *you have the privilege to carry out* (there may be exceptions, but this is not one of them).

To handle this situation, you can

- Ask in chat. [There's even a shiny C# room full of people who would know what the title should be](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c)
- Ask the OP to improve it--tell him he'll get more views. ([Credit @ScottWilson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129862/editing-titles-but-i-dont-have-the-expertise-to-improve-it/129863#comment355782_129863))
- Alternatively, just go ahead and edit it. Make it better. Remember, you don't have to make it the *best* title--any clarification/improvement is good. I have no clue what the guy's talking about, but you seem to know, looking at the flag text.  `addressing object specific methods from the static variable DependencyObject.Changed` seems fine to me--it's an *improvement*.

Note that the "static-to-instance" relationship would be something that should go into both the question and the title-- you could edit it so that it asks "How can I access a static thingy from an instance?", and edit the question to ask a similar thing--leaving the DependancyObject thingamajig as an example.

Complete revamps of the question like this are fine, if you're making it less localized.

Comment: the chat room! of course. very good suggestion.

Comment: A third possibility would be to comment on the question, suggesting that the discrepancy between the title and the body be reconciled.  You can appeal to their self-interest, explaining that they'll get better answers by taking the time to make this change.

Comment: @ScottWilson: Oh, good point--edited in :)

Comment: +1 for "there may be exceptions", makes your explanation really well balanced. I (infrequently!) use flags to suggest some "sensitive" edits where I believe appeal to moderator authority can help avoiding edit-war

Comment: Where's my +1?  :)

Comment: @gnat: Yep, even I've had to flag some stuff that doesn't fall within the above criteria.. Irrelevant to post here, so I didn't add it :)

Comment: @Scott technically I got only half the upvotes on this question (rep cap). I usually redeem after-cap-rep for free waffles, but you can have 'em ;-)